# Passing Python instance as opaque ptr across ctypes C-boundary succeeds in Linux but fails in Win32

Tags: c, python-2.7, winapi, callback

I have a Python2.7 ctypes C-lib wrapper with callback functions called from the C-layer back into Python. This works successfully under Linux but is not entirely working in Windows. My wrapper is a Python class that passes itself into the C functions as the `void*` opaque user-data that C-callbacks commonly use to pass back the user's class or closure for event-handling. The callback gets invoked, but casting the parameter from that callback back into a Python instance is what fails. I get "ValueError: NULL pointer access".

The code that works in Linux is as follows:

When calling the ctypes-wrapped C initialization function from my Python wrapper, I cast `self` instance to a `c_void_p` before passing it in as the C `user_data`. This is stored for future use in the callback and that part at least I can verify has the same value at init time and callback time.

```
c_user_data = ctypes.cast(pointer(ctypes.py_object(self)), c_void_p)
dll_.my_init( on_msg_cb, c_user_data )
```

I map a ctypes message-type structure to it's C-struct counterpart and a callback function the C code uses to pass constructed messages back to my Python code:

```
class msg_evt_type (Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        # ... other field definitions ..
        ('user_data',       c_void_p)
    ]

msg_cb_type = CFUNCTYPE(c_void_p, POINTER(msg_evt_type))

@msg_cb_type
def on_msg_cb(msg_p):
    msg = msg_p[0] # dereference the pointer
    # ...
```

And then within that Python callback invoked by C, I cast the user_data back to my python instance:

```
    # This fails with 'ValueError: NULL pointer access'
    myinst = ctypes.cast(msg.user_data, POINTER(ctypes.py_object)).contents.value
```

Any ideas what needs to be done differently for this to work for Win32?

Comment: Generally it's simpler and cleaner if your callback is a bound method or closure.

Comment: As to a difference here between Linux and Windows, there shouldn't be one. The error implies `msg.user_data` is `NULL` in your Windows version, which implies a problem in your C code, not Python.

Comment: Well, that's a bummer; I'm logging the pointer value in C when it's initially set and then again right before invoking the callback verifying they are identical at these points. Was hoping it was just a problem with my casts.

Comment: Do you keep a reference to `c_user_data`? If not the ctypes pointer gets deallocated, and the `PyObject **` address would become a random address on the heap rather than referencing your object. IIRC, this entire approach also leads to reference leaks. I can't recommend enough that you abandon using this `void *` parameter. It really is pointless and problematic. Bound methods and closures are a much saner option for Python code.

Comment: Thanks, just noticed the additional tip; I hadn't been doing that so I've added it, but doesn't seem to make any difference.

Comment: Please update your question with a simplified, complete problem that recreates the issue. Include C functions to set and call the callback.